# How do I get an updated copy of the environment variables in between bitbucket pipeline steps?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a script that updates keys for docker login.
If I do NOT run the script that updates keys the in a step, the docker login works perfectly.
If I run the update keys script on my local machine, the script works, and the docker login works
If I run the update keys in the pipeline build, the script works but the docker login does NOT work (because the environment variables are not being updated)
The update keys script needs to run before my docker login
How do I get an updated copy of the environment variables in between steps?

```
bitbucket-pipelines.yml
image: node:8.2.1

pipelines: 
  default: 
    - step: 
        name: Update Docker Password for Login 
        script: 
          - npm install aws-sdk request-promise base-64 
          - node build-tools/update-bb-aws-docker-login.js 
    - step: 
        name: Push Server to AWS Repository 
        script: 
          - docker login -u AWS -p $AWS_DOCKER_LOGIN https://$AWS_DOCKER_URL 
          - docker build -t dev . 
          - docker tag dev:latest $AWS_DOCKER_URL/dev:latest 
          - docker push $AWS_DOCKER_URL/dev:latest 

options: 
  docker: true
```